# The difference between these two integrals....

Tags: calculus

Say we have two functions: $\int_b^ax\,dt$ and$\int_b^at\,dt$, where $a = \sin x$ and $b=\cos x$.

How are these integrals evaluated differently? Do we consider the $x$ in the first integral as some constant, which we can then remove from the integral? (Using this logic: $\int_b^ax\,dt$ = $x(t)|^b_a$)? Then for the second, $\int_b^at\,dt$ = $0.5t^2|^b_a$?

Comment: Was this same question not asked half an hour ago?

Comment: @Sobi There was $\int_b^a x\,dx$, not $\int_b^a x\,dt$.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path My apologies in that case.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{\cos x}^{\sin x}x\,dt = x\int_{\cos x}^{\sin x}dt = x\,t \Big|^{\sin x}_{\cos x}= x(\sin x - \cos x)$$

$$\int_{\cos x}^{\sin x}t\,dt = \frac{1}{2}t^2 \Biggr |^{\sin x}_{\cos x} = \frac{1}{2}(\sin^2 x - \cos^2 x)$$